# Tried installing pandas profiling but it was unable to install

Tags: python

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement profiling (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for profiling

Answer (score 0):

The package name for pandas' profiling package is `pandas-profiling`.
If you already have pandas installed, run `python -m pip install pandas-profiling` to install it.